¿Como personalizo una clase para aprovechar el método blits de pygame?
Estaba haciendo una clase que contiene un surface, esta clase hace las operaciones como aumentar tamaño, desaparecerla, dar colisión, etc:
import pygame;
from pygame.locals import QUIT;
class Obj():
  def __init__(self,surface):
    self.image=surface;
    self.x=50;
    self.y=50;
    self.isVisible=True;
    self.dim=[40,40];# [width,height]
  def __getitem__(self,key):
    arr=(
      self.image,
      (self.x, self.y) if self.isVisible else (-2*self.dim[0],0),
      self.dim
    );
    if isinstance(key, slice):
      return arr[key.start:key.stop:key.step];
    else: return arr[key];
  def __iter__(self):
    yield self.image
    if self.isVisible:
      yield (self.x,self.y);
    else:
      yield (-2*self.dim[0],-2*self.dim[1]);
  def __next__(self):
    self.__index=(self.__index if self.__index==3 else -1)+1;
    return self.__getitem__(self.__index);

pygame.init();
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500),pygame.RESIZABLE);
images=[ Obj( pygame.Surface((100,150)) ) ];
images[0].image.fill((255,0,0));
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if QUIT==event.type:
      exit(0);
  screen.blits(images);
  pygame.display.flip();


Pero me da este error:
screen.blits(images);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: blit_sequence should be iterator of (Surface, dest)

El objetivo es aprovechar que blits pide (surface,dest=(x,y)) para dibujar todas las imagen. ¿Como lo hago?.

Si no me equivoco, el problema es que está esperando una tupla de dos objetos (surface y dest) pero tú estás dándole una única cosa en la primera llamada, y otra en la segunda iteración... deberías devolver siempre ambas: yield (self.image, (self.x, self.y) if self.isVisible else (-2*self.dim[0],-2*self.dim[1])). Espero que el ternario esté bien porque hace la leche de tiempo que no pico python, pero debería ser algo así :)

@Benito-B La sintaxis está bien, pero me da los mismos resultados.

Tienes algunos errores al implementar el protocolo iterador y de secuencia, pero no son causantes directos del problema que planteas. Por ejemplo, self.__index no está definido (generaría un AttributeError) si se llama a Obj().__next__(), además, este método deberia emitir un StopIteration en toda llamada sucesiva una vez que el iterador esté agotado. Por otro lado, tu objeto es una secuencia de tres items según __getitem__ pero el protocolo iterador solo retorna dos.
Pero el problema no está causado por nada de eso, es en realidad bastante simple.
Tecnicamente blits debería recibir como argumento un iterable de tuplas con alguna de estas firmas válidas:
Tuple[Surface, Union[Coordinate, RectValue]],
Tuple[Surface, Union[Coordinate, RectValue], Union[RectValue, int]],
Tuple[Surface, Union[Coordinate, RectValue], RectValue, int],

En realidad podrías cumplir con lo requerido sin tocar tu clase solo haciendo algo como:
screen.blits(tuple(img) for img in images)

conviertiendo los objetos Obj en tuplas (en lo que solo interviene tu método __iter__).
Si quisieras cumplir con el requisito usando un un iterable de Obj directamente siempre podrias derivar Obj de tuple. Pero, en realidad, no estás obligado a pasar tuplas, con que sea una secuencia basta, con un matiz que veremos.
Si buscaramos desde dónde se lanza la excepción en el código fuente de pygame.Surface, nos encontrariamos que el error se genera aquí (código C):
while ((item = PyIter_Next(iterator))) {
    if (PySequence_Check(item)) {                         
        itemlength = PySequence_Length(item);            // <<<<<<<<
        if (itemlength > 4 || itemlength < 2) {
            bliterrornum = BLITS_ERR_SEQUENCE_REQUIRED;
            goto bliterror;
        }

PySequence_Length forma parte del protocolo de secuencia de la C-Api de Python y equivale a len() en Python. Básicamente tu clase no implementa __len__ por lo que itemlength será -1 y se generará el error.
Solo necesitas implementar __len__ en tu clase para que el código deje de generar el error que muestras, el protocolo iterador no es necesario que lo implementes si no quieres, con que sea una secuencia  (__getitem__) es suficiente, por ejemplo:
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT


class Obj:
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.image = surface
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50
        self.is_visible = True
        self.dim = [40, 40]  # [width, height]

    @property
    def dest(self):
        if self.is_visible:
            return (self.x, self.y)
        return (-2 * self.dim[0], -2 * self.dim[1])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            if key == 0:
                return self.image
            elif key == 1:
                return self.dest
            else:
                raise IndexError(f"{self.__class__.__name__} index out of range")
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            return (self.image, self.dest)[key.start:key.stop:key.step]
        else:
            raise TypeError(
                f"{self.__class__.__name__} indices must be integers or slices, not {key.__class__.__name__}"
            )
    
    def __len__(self):
        return 2


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE)
images = [Obj(pygame.Surface((100, 150)))]
images[0].image.fill((255, 0, 0))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if QUIT == event.type:
            exit(0)
    screen.blits(images)
    pygame.display.flip()


self.__index fue un error de transcripción :)., ese se inicializa en 0 desde init Gracias.
